# Black out a portion of the screen

Tags: macos

I'm trying to make a screen recording but want to ensure that some personal information does not appear in it. For example, it could be my username in the menu bar, or a portion of an app which has a picture in it. I don't mind if that portion is blocked for the entirely of the recording.

Is there any way to overlay a black box or some image on the screen to block out some personal information in my screen recording? I am trying to do it beforehand so that I don't have to edit the recording and redact the information later.

I tried using Preview, but when I interact with other applications, it falls behind the application window I'm trying to redact.

Comment: Would a Stickies window work?

Comment: Use another [Desktop (Spaces)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) and have only the app that you want on that Space and just record that.  Where in the menu bar is your username?

Comment: @Allan Fast User Switching probably

Comment: True @nohillside but then the easiest solution is to just turn that off for the recording.  That or create another user altogether.

Comment: I've seen lots of video production and I've never seen an app to do "live" redaction.  You either remove it from the shot beforehand or take care of it in post.  Lots of tech videos were produced on machines specific for the purpose, but being cognizant of budgets - make a new user account where no personal info is shared.

Comment: @Allan actually shouldn't have used the menu bar item example, my bad. I'm trying to blur out a portion of an application which I can't crop out (like the middle of the screen)

Comment: Like @Allan said, you do it in *post* Record the screen cast and block or blur out those parts of the screen in your video editing app in the previously recorded footage. That's how they do it in professional situations.

Comment: For sure, but I'm wondering if there's a quick way to do it from the beginning. For example there is utility called [GeekTool](https://www.tynsoe.org/v2/geektool/) which used to do this, although it hasn't been updated for a while.